# Django extend UTF-8

Tags: python, html, django

I just started learning Django few days ago, and something is a bit weird. I actually use Visual Studio 2017 with the extension for Django. I created a new project with the Visual studio template. My problem is that the UTF-8 works only on my layout.html when I extend it on other pages, here is some code :

**Layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"  charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }} - My Django Application</title> <!-- Titre de la page modifiable dans /template/app/views.py -->
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/site.css' %}" />
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Barre de navigation -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header" id="red">
                <!-- Menu format mobile/petite page -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- Titre du site -->
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Site de test</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Barre de navigation : Selection des pages -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Présentation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">A propos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Me contacter</a></li>
                </ul>
                {% include 'app/loginpartial.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contenu de la page -->
    <div class="container body-content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; {{ year }} - Site de test</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'app/scripts/respond.js' %}"></script>
{% block scripts %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**About.html (where I use the Layout.html):**

```
<!-- On inclue le layout (navbar + footer) -->
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ title }}.</h2> <!-- Titre de la page modifiable dans /template/app/views.py -->
<h3>{{ message }}</h3>

<p> é à è ù</p>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is the error :

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 224: invalid continuation byte
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was:

� � �

I don't know why the meta charset="UTF-8" doesn't work on the About.html while there is a "é" in the Layout.html.

Comment: It is possible that your Visual Studio does not save the file in UTF-8 which might cause it to break. Though, I'm not known with Visual Studio, but it might give you a lead where to search.

Comment: Yes, I think it could be that. But isn't it a bit weird that the Layout.html file load normaly with an "é" ?